# For my Heat I want to change the players speed but its not working

Tags: unity, 2d

I have a heat bar for my player and I want it so if the player is at 40 heat or under the players speed slows. This is my script. The problem is when the player gets to under 40 heat the speed is not changing. Is this because I have a player speed on my movement script?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHeat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHeat = 100;
    public float currentHeat;
    public float heatLossPerSecond;
    public float moveSpeed = 4f;

    public HeatBar heatBar;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHeat = maxHeat;
        heatBar.SetMaxHeat(maxHeat);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (currentHeat <= 40)
        {
            moveSpeed = 2;
        }

        currentHeat -= heatLossPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        if (currentHeat <= 0)
        {
            currentHeat = 0;
        }
        heatBar.SetHeat(currentHeat);
    }

    public void Heat(float amount)
    {
        currentHeat += amount;
        if (currentHeat > maxHeat)
        {
            currentHeat = maxHeat;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my movement script

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Camera cam;

    Vector2 movement;
    Vector2 mousePos;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        mousePos = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        rb.rotation = angle;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not look like you are setting the new speed value on your movement script. Can you include the movement script too, seems like an easy fix! You are setting the local variable moveSpeed  (local to PlayerHeat) to 2 when the current is equal to or less than 40, but you need to access the movement script and set the speed to this new value, you should also handle what happens when you are above 40 heat, resetting to default or some such.

Comment: I included the movement script now

Comment: I don't see where `moveSpeed` is declared in your movement script. It doesn't look like it's reading it from the heat script. How were you intending for these two scripts to communicate with one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to make sure you either drag the `PlayerMovementScript` into the slot on the PlayerHeat script or use `GetComponent<ScriptName>()` if it is on the same object!**

What is worth bearing in mind is, all "MonoBehaviour" Scripts are Components that live on Game Objects so if you had a MonoBehaviour Script called "PlayerHealth" you could use `this.GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();` to retrieve it.
Then do something like `playerHealth.TakeDamage(damageAmount);` to call **public** functions on it or, as you see below public fields(variables)

You would do something like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerHeat : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHeat = 100;
    public float currentHeat;
    public float heatLossPerSecond;
    public float moveSpeed = 4f;
    //either drag your player movement script into this slot in the inspector 
    public PlayerMovement playerMovementScript;
            

    public HeatBar heatBar;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHeat = maxHeat;
        //or if the script is on the same object you can just do 
        //GetComponent<ScriptName>();
        playerMovementScript = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();
        heatBar.SetMaxHeat(maxHeat);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (currentHeat <= 40)
        {
            //here we set the moveSpeed variable of playerMovementScript to the new 
            //speed!
            playerMovementScript.moveSpeed =  2;
        }
       else
       {
           //You can reset the value here if you go above 40 heat, or not, upto you!
            playerMovementScript.moveSpeed =  2;
       }

        currentHeat -= heatLossPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
        if (currentHeat <= 0)
        {
            currentHeat = 0;
        }
        heatBar.SetHeat(currentHeat);
    }

    public void Heat(float amount)
    {
        currentHeat += amount;
        if (currentHeat > maxHeat)
        {
            currentHeat = maxHeat;
        }
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks so much!